# Select Node Type From XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Hi i have a scenario where i want to search the node in xml file and identify the type of file.

```
XDocument xDococumnetObj = XDocument.Load(filePath);
XElement presentationElement= 
      xDococumnetObj.Descendants()
                    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("collegge"))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I have written query which returns me collegge node. But i just want to identify the type of document it is. I want to identify the document whether it contains `{"Collegge","University","Company","Banking"}` in single query and return its Type only.

Comment: What do you mean by **Type** of document? Can you bring sample of xml?

Comment: i mean the node name in document can be either {"Collegge","University","Company","Banking"}. so based on that would like to find which Type of document it is.Either collegge type or Company type or Banking type etc.

Comment: By type i mean i can return either string as type or first xElement as value. in Type.Based on that i will perform operations on the document.

Comment: Are node names lowCase in your xml? Do they have namespaces? Is it root node name?

Comment: I removed the Tolower() check and it worked.The nodes were as it was shown in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] docTypes = {"Collegge", "University", "Company", "Banking"};
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var docType = docTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => 
                xdoc.Descendants().Any(n => n.Name.LocalName == type.ToLower()));
```

**UPDATE:** If all elements declared in same namespace, you can use following code to avoid traversing all elements from files

```
string[] docTypes = {"Collegge", "University", "Company", "Banking"};
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.foo.org/2013/bar";
var docType = docTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => xdoc.Descendants(ns + type).Any());
```

Comment: Thank you sir this is working solution.Just removed tolower check. :)

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal welcome :) sorry, but I can't give you better solution without seeing xml (possibly checking all nodes can be avoided here)

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky :) Yeah thats perfectly fine sir.Its fast since FirstOrDefault is used and returns the value as soon as it gets one in the document.

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal but if there is no such value, then whole document is looped till the end. I believe that can be avoided. But if you have small documents, that's not issue :)

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky .Can we use any other approach to find out whether  xml document contains the node name as said above.Because you pointed out the scenario which is absolutely right, that if document does not have any node as above then it will loop till the end..and it can be bit time consuming.

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal do you have namespaces defined in your xml? If not, then just use `docTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => xdoc.Descendants(type).Any())`

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky. Yes i have namespaces defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26431/discussion-between-lazyberezovsky-and-lokendra-jayaswal)

Comment: @@ lazyberezovsky since Namespaces are there so we have to go by your  approach that is working perfectly fine.But as you pointed out the scenario it would loop through whole document in that case..  :)

Comment: That's the perfect solution.